# Is it possible to use a jquery function such as delegate to listen to jquery ui events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

i want to know if its possible to use a function like `.delegate()`, `.on()` or any in a way that it will listen to jquery UI events such as `draggable`. I have the following:

HTML:

```
  <div id="wrapper"></div>​
```

javaScript:

```
$(function(){

  var addMe='<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><p>Drag me around</p></div>'

  $( "#wrapper" ).delegate('#draggable','draggable',function(){
       console.log('its something!');
  });

  //$(".draggable").draggable();
  $("#wrapper").append(addMe) 
})
```

The element that is going to be `draggable` is dynamically added so that is way i want to use `delegate` or `on`.

Also note that i'm aware of [How do I add draggable List Items from the result of a .ajax GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857143/how-do-i-add-draggable-list-items-from-the-result-of-a-ajax-get) and even that solution can work for me i have to modify the .post() function which is not what i'm asking.

Here is the [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/yTBkk/13/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common question....how to use delegation to invoke plugins , and there is no holy grail like `on()`. In the case of almost all jQueryUI widgets there is far more involved than simply binding events, the html and element data needs to be connstructed.

ALthough there is no delegation method, you can use $.ajaxComplete() as a global handler to initialize plugins , if it suits your application. It can be bound to any element,  which allows using `this` within handler

```
 $('#content').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
     /* url conditional*/
      if (settings.url == 'getMoreDraggables.php') {
            $(this).find('.newDraggable').removeClass('newDraggable').draggable()
      }
      /* element conditional */
     if( $(this).find('.newDraggable').length){  
        /* run code for true*/
     }

});
```

Can also add conditionals based on xhr object

Comment: Thank you! i did not know about this `ajaxComplete()`. Although it's by default fired when any ajaxComplete event is finished i wonder why you can not `jail` it to a selector, using a conditional to see if it's applicable sounds like a waste of computing time.

Comment: that's part of the flexibility, could bind it to document even. Or could have several attached for different elements. Is cross browser friendly too, whereas other solution I don't think is and would require a shim. Instead of global, to not have it run each time use the ajax callbacks themselves

Comment: sorry i didnt meant that you cant, i mean that the ajaxComplete will be fired every time a ajax is completed, it wont be only fired when the selector to which is attached gets completed. Or at least that is what the documents says.

Comment: then use the callbacks of the actual call, or deffereds. Can set up a cutom event that fires for pageload elemnts, then use `trigger` to do same in ajax `success`

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use event delegation to automatically create jQuery UI widgets.  Your best bet is to explicitly destroy and recreate.

```
$('.draggable').draggable('destroy');
$('.draggable').draggable();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hTCLB/

Comment: Hm, not sure that is true. http://jsfiddle.net/hTCLB/2/ putting that above the `$('#wrapper').append(addMe) is not working. Your solution seems to work eventually as the dom is finally ready.

Comment: @EH_warch Right I'm saying that what the OP is asking is not possible.  The fiddle shows that you just need to explicitly call those 2 lines after the DOM changes have been made.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just execute a function calling the `.draggable()` in the callback of your Ajax requests?

Otherwise, you can observe the wrapper with a [DOM Mutation Observer](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) and use an anonymous function to call the `.draggable()` when new elements are appended. It's very similar to event delegation as you asked, but I'm not sure how good that is for older versions of IE.

Example code with Observer:

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length) {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        }
    });
});
observer.observe($('#wrapper')[0], { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

[**JSFiddle with DOM Mutation Observer**](http://jsfiddle.net/4xcRJ/)

[Reference](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Also, if you can't use the Ajax call's callback for this, odds are there is a logic/design flaw in your application. I'd suggest taking a look on that before shoving down hacks as the DOM Mutation Observer.

Comment: As for the first paragraph nop, that is the answer gotten in the post i mention on my question. But i'm going to look foward on link you provide, you have examples?

Comment: JSFiddle is going really slow for me atm, but I should have some examples - even though, the MDN page already has a a couple. `=]` I'll take a look at my examples folder.

Comment: @EH_warch I couldn't find any in my folder so I wrote one from scratch, check if it helps.