# JQuery losing draggable ability on ajax returned data

Tags: jquery

Wondering if someone can help, basically I have two div containers, both droppable. Container 1 has an ajax populated list of images and each image can be dragged from Container 1 to Container 2 and back again. Problem is that it only works on a static coded image but loses the draggable ability when using dynamic content from ajax (the images appear inside Container 1 so the ajax part is working). If anyone can suggest a possible solution as I am really scratching my head with this. Thank you.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var currentParent;

        $(".image").resizable({
            containment: "parent"
        }).draggable({
            revert: 'invalid',
            start: function(){
                currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            }
        });

    $('#container2').droppable({
        accept:'.image',
        drop: function(event,ui){
            if (currentParent != $(this).attr('id')){
              $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
              alert("Dropped into workspace");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#container1').droppable({
        accept:'.image',
        drop: function(event,ui){
            if (currentParent != $(this).attr('id')){
              $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
              alert("Put back into menu");
            }
        }
    });

     $.ajax({  
      url: 'images/retrieve_images.php',    
      data: 'page_id='+ encodeURIComponent(page_id),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            $.each(val, function(k, v) {
                $("<div class='image'><img width='auto' height='100%' src='article_images/"+v.image_name+"'/></div>").appendTo("#container1");
            });
        });

        }

    });

});

</script>
```

If I run a static image it works perfect:

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="image"><img width="auto" height="100%" src="article_images/c5cfe4711ec60b5a676ae386702a8051.png"/></div>
</div>

<div id="container2"></div>
```

Comment: Since the images don't yet exist when you are binding the elements to the event, you have to bind the event to a delegate using `delegate()` or `on()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a jquery function such as delegate to listen to jquery ui events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249674/is-it-possible-to-use-a-jquery-function-such-as-delegate-to-listen-to-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason Why Draggable Is Not Working**

When you initialized `draggable()` for the first time this elements where not there so it wont get binded . So you need to bind that after adding.

**Solution-1**

Re initialize draggable by below code in AJAX success

```
$('.image').draggable('destroy');
$('.image').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function() {
      currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    }
  });
```

**Solution-2**

Make a function like this and call it in AJAX sucess

```
function dragable() {
  $(".image").resizable({
    containment: "parent"
  }).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function() {
      currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    }
  });
}
```

It will look something like this

```
success: function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    $.each(val, function(k, v) {
      $("<div class='image'><img width='auto' height='100%' src='article_images/" + v.image_name + "'/></div>").appendTo("#container1");
    });
  });

  function dragable()// added the function call
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rino, I now see what you mean by initialising draggable without any elements available. It now works perfectly, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add *draggable* to each item in the ajax success call as below

```
 $.ajax({  
  url: 'images/retrieve_images.php',    
  data: 'page_id='+ encodeURIComponent(page_id),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        $.each(val, function(k, v) {
            $("<div class='image'><img width='auto' height='100%' src='article_images/"+v.image_name+"'/></div>")
           .draggable({
                        revert: 'invalid',
                        start: function(){
                            currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                        }
           }).appendTo("#container1");
        });
    });

    }

});
```